# How to avoid duplicated DB content when persisting EJB entities created by a JSF component converter?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, ejb, ejb-3.0

I have a custom JSF input component, named inputPeriod, which is designed to input date-periods. Each period has a from and to date. The functionality of the component is achieved with Javascript, which generates a JSON string and submits it to the component. The input component then use a default converter which converts the JSON periods into a list of Period objects and sets them on my managed bean. This all works perfectly.

The source of the problem I am having, is that now I want to use the same component with EJB entities. I have a Banner entity with a one-to-many relationship with a BannerPeriod entity. Each instance of the BannerPeriod entity takes a from (begins) and to (ends) date, exactly like the existing Period object I am using with my input component. I have implemented a new converter for this:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BannerPeriodConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String str) {
        if (str != null) {
            Date from = null, to = null;
            try {
                JSONObject period = new JSONObject(str);
                if (period.has("from")) {
                    from = new Date(period.getLong("from"));
                }
                if (period.has("to")) {
                    to = new Date(period.getLong("to"));
                }
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                throw new ConverterException(ex);
            }
            BannerPeriod bp = new BannerPeriod();
            bp.setBegins(from);
            bp.setEnds(to);
            return bp;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) {
        if (o != null && o instanceof BannerPeriod) {
            BannerPeriod bp = (BannerPeriod) o;
            JSONObject period = new JSONObject();
            try {
                period.put("from", bp.getBegins() != null ? bp.getBegins().getTime() : (Object) null);
                period.put("to", bp.getEnds() != null ? bp.getEnds().getTime() : (Object) null);
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                throw new ConverterException(ex);
            }
            return period.toString();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

The converter works fine with the component. The issue I am having is that when I edit a banner with existing banner periods, the entities lose their primary key. So, when I submit my form, instead of updating existing periods, I either get a duplicate exception or the existing periods are created again, making actual duplicates in the database.

So my question is, what can I do to avoid this? My guess would be that the input component somehow needs to keep the primary key on the existing entities, but how can I best make something like that? At the moment, the input component is completely detached from the entities and my EJB project. The input component is even located in its own JSF project, while the converter above is located in an EJB project. By default the input component works with a plain Period object, which has no primary key at all. It should continue to do so.

Or maybe this should be solved in some other way?

Comment: If you changed the EJB save method to 1) delete the previous periods of the same banner and then 2) add the new ones, would this solve your problem?

Comment: In this specific case it probably would. However, I do see several cases later in my project, where it would not be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `getAsObject()` you're creating a completely unmanaged instance of `BannerPeriod` instead of obtaining the one straight from DB via JPA.

```
BannerPeriod bp = new BannerPeriod();
bp.setBegins(from);
bp.setEnds(to);
return bp;
```

Persisting it will of course create a new entry in DB as it's unmanaged by JPA.

Basically, you should instead be obtaining the instance from the DB via JPA:

```
@EJB
private BannerPeriodService service;

public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    // ...

    return service.find(from, to);
}
```

wherein the `BannerPeriodService#find()` obtains the desired instance via `EntityManager`.

But this approach is pretty clumsy. In case of entities from the DB, the canonical approach is to use their technical/natural identifier for this, such as the autogenerated primary key.

E.g. (null/instanceof checks and so on omitted):

```
@EJB
private BannerPeriodService service;

public Object getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    Long id = ((BannerPeriod) value).getId();
    return id.toString();
}

public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    Long id = Long.valueOf(value);
    return service.find(id);
}
```

No need to mess up with JSON format. If you *actually* need them in JSON format for some unclear reason, then you're going in the wrong direction by using a JSF converter for this.

I understand that hitting the DB in a converter is a relatively expensive job. In that case, the OmniFaces [`SelectItemsConverter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: My component set from/to dates on BannerPeriod entities, without knowing about the entity object thanks to JSON. It is all encapsulated in the converter. My component does not select BannerPeriod entities. If I make a converter that look up the entity by ID in getAsObject and return the ID in getAsString, then how would the component actually set the from/to date on each entity? Wouldn't it just select BannerPeriod entities, which isn't the functionality I'm after here?

Comment: However, looking up the entity by from/to in getAsObject might actually do the trick. It does mean that changing the from/to date would make the banner period appear new, instead of changed, but it's a step in the right direction and it definitely solves the duplicate exception.

Comment: @BalusC Where should check for duplicate entry to a `jsf` form? In `Data Access layer` Or in `view layer` ?